# How can a function know its calling function's decorator

Tags: python, decorator, code-inspection

I have two decorators, @timeout and @retry
code is like this

```
@timeout(seconds=1)
def func_inner(expire):
    time.sleep(expire)

@retry(
    count=2,
    message="Failed command after {expire} seconds",
)
def func(expire):
    func_inner(expire)
```

I just want to know how can method func() know func_inner has a decorator @timeout? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a function grab decorator attached to the function inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374233/how-can-a-function-grab-decorator-attached-to-the-function-inside)

Comment: Okay, final answer, I re-edited and included three  easy ways to do it in one line.  Please see if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
@timeout(seconds=1)
def func_inner(expire):
    time.sleep(expire)
```

Is essentially equal to:

```
def func_inner(expire):
    time.sleep(expire)

func_inner = timeout(seconds=1)(func_inner)
```

Method `func` simply calls `func_inner(expire)`, which is the same as calling `timeout(seconds=1)(func_inner)(expire)` since the decorator has redefined the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see the wrapper inside the function, using inspect or globals, and you can access the wrapper object directly.

Here is a simple example showing some ways to see the wrapper inside the function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import inspect

def mydecorator(func):
    def mywrapper():
        print( 'in mywrapper' )
        func()
    return mywrapper

@mydecorator
def myfunc():
    felf = globals()[inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).function]
    print("** myfunc inspect : %s"%felf.__name__)

    felf = globals()[sys._getframe().f_code.co_name]
    print("** myfunc globals : %s"%felf.__name__)

    print( 'wrapper =' )
    print( myfunc )

    print( 'done myfunc' )


myfunc()

print( 'wrapper =' )
print( myfunc )
```

The above prints out,

```
in mywrapper
** myfunc inspect : mywrapper
** myfunc globals : mywrapper
wrapper =
<function mywrapper at 0x7f30df0e72a8>
done myfunc
wrapper =
<function mywrapper at 0x7f30df0e72a8>
```

Note that the name is not the name of your function, but instead it is the wrapper.  See the inspect and getframe documentation for more about what information is available.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting it would only be possible through some specific mechanism defined by the decorator itself. A decorator just takes a function and returns another object in the general case, and Python itself does not keep a record of this process.